# Pagination with $_GET - in AJAX - is it posible

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a PHP class for pagination using $_GET. It is standart, found from the web.

Here it works good : 
page.php :

```
<form method ="GET">
<?php 
$pages = new Pagination();
echo "<br/>";
?>   
</form>
```

I want to use this page.php in index.php with ajax / jquery and staying in the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<body>
<div id ="result"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('./page.php', 
            function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data); 
            } 
    );  
});

</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Is this possible way ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that instead of using jquery's $.post, that you can replace $.post with $.get?

Answer (score 1):

So instead of `$.post` as you said its looking for `$_GET['page']`

So you could do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var page_num = 1;
    $('.nextpage').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from going anywhere
        $.get('./page.php',
            {
                page: page_num // this is the same as $_GET['page']
            },
            function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                page_num++;
            } 
        );  
    });

    $('.nextpage').click(); // emulate the click to get the first page 
});
</script>
```

and in your body something like this:

```
<a href="/page.php?page=2" class="nextpage">Next page</a>
```

It's worth noting that on your `page.php` you don't need to have that form as i cannot see it's going to be doing much

**UPDATE**

So to have the pagination manipulated on the `index.php` from `page.php` you could have `page.php` return a hidden div called `.hidden_pagination` along with its full content.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.pagination').on('click','a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from going anywhere

        var next_page = $(this).attr('data-id'); // get the next page from the link data-id attribute
        $.get('./page.php',
            {
                page: next_page // this is the same as $_GET['page']
            },
            function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);

                $('.pagination').html($('#result').children('.hidden_pagination').html()); // add the new pagination to the current pagination
            } 
        );  
    });

    $('.nextpage').click(); // emulate the click to get the first page 
});
</script>

<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#" class="nextpage" data-id="2">Next page</a>
</div>


<div id="result">
 this will be replaced with the ajax response
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was a silly mistake really, but I would like to stay AT index.php and manipulate the pagination in page.php. Probably I should do this with <iframe>

Comment: hmmm i see, so what i would suggest is on the page.php return a hidden input element (div) that has the manipulated pagination in.. then you can update your index.php pagination with the new information - i will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Are you sure that's the right way, because <div class ="hidden_pagination" > 
    <form method ="GET">
        <?php $pages1 = new Pagination(); echo "<hr/>"; ?>   
    </form>
</div> doesn't help much(that's in page.php so it retrives a div)

Comment: on your ajax response, if you have a hidden div with a class of `hidden_pagination` it will update your `index.php` pagination with the one returned from `page.php`.. is this not what you wanted?

Comment: you may need to alter your Pagination class slightly, however the method is tried and tested as i have used this in several projects in the past.. If you want me to run through it with what you currently have we should start a chat

Comment: OK, I'll make an attempt to find you in the chat these days